A linear map preserves generalized eigenspaces.
Let $V, W$ be vector spaces over a field $K$ of finite dimension. $f: V\to V$ and $g: W\to W$ are linear transformations. $\phi: V\to W$ is a surjective linear map such that $\phi f=g\phi$．$V\supseteq \tilde V_a = \bigcup _{n=0}^\infty \ker {(f-a)}^{n}$ is the generalized eigenspace with respect to $f$ and $W\supset \tilde W_a$ is as same.
How to prove $\phi \tilde{V_a} = \tilde{W_a}$? It's clear that $\phi \tilde{V_a}\subseteq \tilde{W_a}$, but the inverse seems difficult. I wonder the following statement is true: $$W=W'\oplus\bigoplus_{a \in K} \tilde W_a\supset  \phi V'\oplus\bigoplus_{a\in K} \phi \tilde{V_a} = \phi (V'\oplus \bigoplus_{a ∈ K} \tilde V_a) = \phi V = W.$$ So we get $\bigoplus_{a \in K} \tilde{W_a} = \bigoplus_{a\in K} \phi \tilde{V_a}$. This leads to $\tilde{W_a} = \phi\tilde{V_a}$.
Or, I think we can compare the dimensions of $\phi\tilde V_a$ and $\tilde W_a$ by using the fact that the characteristic polynomial of $g$ divides the characteristic polynomial of $f$ under this condition and the dimension of $\tilde W_a$ is equal to the multiplicity of $a$ of the characteristic polynomial.
Further more, I believe there is a proof with good use of dual spaces.
I appreciate your help (I'm not good at English, so please do not hesitate to correct my English).

I'm assuming $\mathbb K$ is algebraically closed (or at least a splitting field for the characteristic polynomial of $f$).  $f$ has $m$ distinct eigenvalues and minimal polynomial $p(x) = \prod_{k=1}^mp_k(x) = \prod_{k=1}^m(x-\lambda_k)^{m_k}$.  And $\mathbf 0 = \phi\cdot p(f)=p(g)\cdot \phi$.  Since $\phi$ is surjective this means $p$ kills $g$ hence $p$ is divisible by the minimal polynomial of $g$.  This implies that any non-trivial generalized eigenspace $ \bigcup _{n=0}^\infty \ker {(g-a)}^{n} =\ker p_k(g)$ for some $k$.
For $k\in\big\{1,2,\dots, m\}$ we have $\phi\cdot p_k(f)=p_k(g)\cdot\phi $ and $V =\text{image }p(f) \oplus \ker p(f)$ where $\phi$ respects both of these invariant subspaces, i.e. for $v' \in \text{image }p_k(f) $ we have
$\phi v' =\phi\cdot  p_k(f) v = p_k(g) \cdot\phi v \implies \phi \cdot v'\in \text{image }  p_k(g)\implies \phi\cdot \text{image }p_k(f)\subseteq \text{image }  p_k(g)$.
For $v \in \ker p_k(f)$we have :  $p_k(g)\cdot \phi v = \phi\cdot  p_k(f) v = 0\implies \phi v \in \ker p_k(g)$
$\implies \phi \cdot\ker p_k(f) \subseteq \ker p_k(g)$
Since $\text{image } p_k(f)  + \ker  p_k(f) = \text{image } p_k(f)  \oplus \ker  p_k(f)=V$, we may write
$\phi \cdot\text{image } p_k(f) + \phi \cdot\ker  p_k(f)=\phi V =W=\text{image }p_k(g) \oplus \ker p_k(g)$
checking dimensions:
$\dim \phi V \leq \dim\phi\cdot\text{image } p_k(f)  + \dim \phi\cdot\ker  p_k(f)$ $\leq \dim\text{image }p_k(g) +\dim \ker p_k(g) = \dim W$
which is met with equality $\implies\dim \phi\cdot\ker  p_k(f) =\dim \ker p_k(g)$
$\implies \phi \cdot \ker p_k(f)=\ker p_k(g)$
